# Embed SVG into HTML (Opera-specific)

Tags: html, svg, embed, opera

I want to embed SVG image into UserJS script for Opera. The question is how to show this image on loaded page?

I show PNG images using `<img src='data://image/png;base64,...'>`, but SVG images aren't shown being used this way. Using external SVG file is OK, but not 'data://image/svg+xml,...'.

I can't embed SVG code to HTML directly, because not every page is XHTML.
I can use `<object type='image/svg+xml' data='data://image/svg+xml,.../>`, but then 'click' event doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click events work fine in `<object>`, but you'll have to catch the events inside the svg and not on the `<object>` element. You can get the embedding element from there easily: `window.frameElement`.

But I don't see why it shouldn't work in `<img>` elements, unless there's something wrong with the svg itself. I tested a simple example (though not in a userJS script) in Opera 10 build 1497 (WinXP) and it worked fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've found my error: those slashes after 'data:' are invalid. For some reason it doesn't affects GIF and PNG, but affects SVG images.

Comment: Those slashes would probably be interpreted as being part of the mediatype, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397 for details.

Then for the binary formats I think there's content sniffing involved, which is probably why you can see the image in those cases.

Comment: I have a related question here on how you created that data URI value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687546/what-is-the-value-of-an-embedded-svg-in-a-data-uri-and-what-is-the-tag-to-use?noredirect=1#comment109115686_61687546