# What is the value of an embedded SVG in a data URI and what is the tag to use?

Tags: html, svg

If I have this SVG:

```
<body> 
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <text x="10" y="50" font-size="30" class="svgClass2" id="svgText2">My SVG</text>
   </svg> 
</body>
```

IIUC If I want to embed that SVG markup to a data URI then I would convert that SVG markup to base64 and set it as the source of an image tag?

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,charset=utf-8;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmN==" />
```

Is the value `PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmN...` this:

```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <text x="10" y="50" font-size="30" class="svgClass2" id="svgText2">My SVG</text>
   </svg>
```

Is that correct?

**Additional Questions if possible:**
Is it still interactive as an img? 
Do classes still apply? 
Does the ID still apply? 
Is it smaller in size as data URI base64?

Note: There is a specific use case where this will be used. I am aware of some of the pros and cons.

**References**:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/882783/441016 - Data URI in image tag

https://vecta.io/blog/best-way-to-embed-svg - this does not show examples but the comments people talk about data URI

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Comment: I'm not getting what your asking. The top one is already embeded as the SVG isn't getting loaded from an external source. The text is getting drawn from the <text> tag. The xmlns is just a ruleset? I think, but it doesn't actually load anything. From my understanding.

Comment: I'm talking about embedding as a data URI. Question updated.

Comment: At this question here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/882783/441016, a guy is using <img src="data:image/svg+xml,...."> to display SVG. How did he get to that? Did he put the entire SVG markup into a base64 encoder and then paste that value into an image tag?

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion for the first answer, here is how to convert an SVG to base64 so that you can embed it inside of an `<img>` tag.

Yes, you just need to pipe the following structure to a base64 encoder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="537" height="474" viewBox="-3 6 358 316">
...
</svg>
```

This is just a pseudo-example, of course use your custom `width`, `height` and `viewBox` and fill in the graphics markup. If you want to compress it a bit, you can minify the svg code upfront.

## Quick manual solution

1. Get your svg, for example [this ♡](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/ArrowHeart.svg).
2. Use this converter to get the base64 text: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/svg
3. Select the option to generate an `img` tag right away or do it manually: `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,` *obtained-plain-base64-string* `">`.

You can see the [converted ♡ in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suapkv3h/).

## Automated solution

If you are interested in programmatic conversion to base64, you will for sure find resources for the language/framework of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to embed it

Not sure what you mean, it already *is* embeded in the page in your first example.

> then I would convert that string to base64 and set it as the source of an image tag?

you could, but I don't see any possible benefit.

> Is it still interactive?

No. SVGs in `img` tags lose interactivity.

> Do classes still apply?

If they're applied from the page, no.

> Does the ID still apply?

IDs in the SVG won't be visible from elsewhere in the page, if that's what you mean.

> Is it smaller in size as base64?

No, it will be 33% larger.

Comment: I assume by _embedding_ he is referring to the following: https://vecta.io/blog/best-way-to-embed-svg. Most of the answers are already there. `<img>` is isolated from the rest of the site and non-interactive.

Comment: More details on the base64 length here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation

Comment: I'm asking how to convert SVG markup (and what part) into data URI as base64. Question updated.